# Wrong result set with Many-to-Many JPQL

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpql

I have a Many to Many relation between Shop Product and Category. Multiple shops have same/multiple products. Each product belongs to multiple Categories. I want to get list of products in a particular shop with given Category Id.

```
        sql = "select shop.products as products from Shop shop" +
                " join shop.products product" +
                " join product.categories category" +
                " where shop.id = :shopId and category.id = :categoryId";
```

Shop has something like :

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "shops")
private List<Product> products;
```

Product has:

```
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name = "Products_Categories", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "Product_ID")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "Category_ID")})
private Set<Category> categories;

@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name = "Shop_Product", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "Product_ID")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "Shop_ID")})
private Set<Shop> shops = new HashSet<>();
```

and in Category I have something like :

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "categories")
private List<Product> products;
```

However the result set from above query have all the data irrespective of the category provided.

Generated SQL

```
select product6_.id as id1_4_, product6_.calories as calories2_4_, product6_.createdDate as createdD3_4_, product6_.description as descript4_4_, product6_.modifiedDate as modified5_4_, product6_.name as name6_4_, product6_.price as price7_4_ from Shop shop0_
  inner join Shop_Product products1_ on shop0_.id=products1_.Shop_ID
  inner join Products product2_ on products1_.Product_ID=product2_.id
  inner join Products_Categories categories3_ on product2_.id=categories3_.Product_ID
  inner join Categories category4_ on categories3_.Category_ID=category4_.id
  inner join Shop_Product products5_ on shop0_.id=products5_.Shop_ID
  inner join Products product6_ on products5_.Product_ID=product6_.id where
  shop0_.id=? and category4_.id=?
```

**Update: Issue is because the generated sql has extra joins. Check line 6 and 7 in SQL. That is not required. How can I avoid it?**

Comment: I told you on a previous question you CANNOT SELECT MULTI-VALUED FIELDS in JPQL. Why are you still doing it?

Comment: @DN1 but i was able select product from Shop.

Comment: because it isnt a MULTI-VALUED field!

Comment: @DN1 thanks.... But I get the result set if I write "select shop.products from Shop shop". Can you share the link which helps me understand multi-valued.

Comment: Read the JPA SPEC! It defines the API that you are using. All JPA providers have their own documentation too, so I have to assume you have actually read it. Here's one http://www.datanucleus.org:15080/products/accessplatform_5_1/jpa/query.html#jpql_bnf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue by tweaking the query a bit:

```
        sql = "select product from Shop shop" +
                " join shop.products product" +
                " join product.categories category" +
                " where shop.id = :shopId and category.id = :categoryId";
```